# Trying to compile DWM on Centos 7.2 - missing freetype/config/ftheader.h

Tags: centos, x11, compiling, dwm

```
/usr/include/ft2build.h:56:38: fatal error: freetype/config/ftheader.h: No such file or directory
#include <freetype/config/ftheader.h>
```

I have freetype-devel installed. There are no other freetype devel packages to install.

Answer (score 1):

As there is a `/usr/include/freetype2/config/ftheader.h` in `freetype-devel`, and assuming that a file called `ft2build.h` actually means freetype2 by "freetype", you could try creating a symbolic link `ln -s /usr/include/freetype2 /usr/include/freetype`.

But you should ask, where did the "ft2build.h" file come from? Does it have any `#ifdef` around the `#include` that makes it choose that wrong path?

You could build from the source rpms instead. Eg on my fedora 22:

```
yumdownloader --source  dwm
rpm -i dwm-6.0-11.fc22.src.rpm 
rpmbuild -ba ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/dwm.spec
```

Answer (score 1):

Comment the line in `config.mk`:
`FREETYPEINC = ${X11INC}/freetype2`
This worked for me on `Ubuntu 17.10`

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `/usr/include/freetype2` in your "include path".  This may be done by passing

```
-I/usr/include/freetype2
```

during compile time, or there may be an option to the DWM configure script.

Comment: config.mk has the following which includes that directory:

    FREETYPEINC = /usr/include/freetype2
    INCS = -I${X11INC} -I${FREETYPEINC}